# What are those threads the debugger reports SDL is spawning at initialization?

Tags: c, multithreading, curl, sdl

I noticed that on a single threaded application, SDL still spawns some threads on initialization. It's usually not of my concern by I noticed cURL requires its initialization to be done before any thread creation for thread-safety. Can they generally be ignored [for cURL initialization] or not? [Also, are they just a sign of using an external library etc.?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grepping the source, it looks like the audio subsystem can utilize threading on most platforms, as well as the event subsystem on some platforms (mostly X11 it seems).

Answer (score 1):

> cURL requires its initialization to be done before any thread creation for thread-safety

It doesn't mean the universe will implode if you create any thread (well, you've already created one by starting the process) before initialising it. It means that you can't have multiple threads calling cURL routines before initialisation (because it has to create synchronisation primitives, etc.).

Since SDL doesn't call cURL at any point, the initialisation order doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: The problem is "This function is not thread safe. You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init() calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries. " From curl_global_init doc.

Comment: @Lela: That's hopefully just over-paranoia on curl's part. If they really do idiotic things like poking at stateful/non-reentrant libc functions (`strtok`?) during initialization, I would assume that library is full of bugs and not use it.

Comment: cURL is the de facto standard of a downloading library in the open source world at the moment.